# how to repeat the rows dynamically in .html() jqueryajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

In the below code am having one table with values from database.After executing the the query if am having 5 values am getting only the first value in my table(inside pop up).in this html() function how can i add the foreach and type of parametrs for for each,
i used ajax,json,jquery

My code is;

```
success: function (msg) {
    var data = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(eval("(" + msg.d + ")")));

    $('<div></div>')
        .appendTo('body')
        .html('<div><b>SHAREHOLDER DETAILS</b></br>' + data.Id + '</div>' + 
              '<div>' + data.name + '</div>' + 
              '<div>' + data.Id + '</div>' + 
              '<table border="1" style="background-color:silver;"><tr>' + 
              '<td>' + 'OwnedBy' + '</td>' + 
              '<td>' + 'ShareClass' + '</td>' + 
              '<td>' + 'EffectiveInterest' + '</td>' + 
              '<td>' + 'DeemedInterest' +'</td>' + 
              '<td>' + 'SharesOwned' + '</td>' + 
              '<td>' + 'SharesIssued' + '</td>' + 
              '</tr>' + 
              '<tr>' + 
              '<td>' + data.Id +'</td>' + 
              '<td>' + data.share + '</td>' + 
              '<td>' + data.effect + '</td>' + 
              '<td>' + data.deemed + '</td>' + 
              '<td>' + data.owned + '</td>' + 
              '<td>' + data.issued + '</td>' + 
              '</tr>' + 
              '</table>')
        .dialog({
            modal: true, 
            title: '<div>' + data.Id + '</div>', 
            zIndex: 10000, 
            autoOpen: true, 
            position: ['right', 'top'],
            width: 'auto', 
            height: 'auto', 
            modal: false, 
            resizable: false, 
            closeOnEscape: false,
            show: "slide", 
            hide: "explode",
            close: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).remove();
            }
        });
},
```

Comment: First, please format your code so it's readable. Second, try to avoid manually interpreting JSON (eg., `eval()`). Third, voting to close; there's plenty of `for` loop tutorials and questions on this site, and this is textbook "too localized". Also, I have no idea what those two `**` are doing in that table markup; that's not valid markup.

Answer (score 0):

You need some sort of iterator function, as you have it the code will only pull the first value.

My suggestion would be to use .each:

```
var element = $('<table></table>').appendTo('body');
jQuery.each(data, function(i, val) {
    element.append(
        '<tr>' +
        '<td>' + val.Id +'</td>' + 
        '<td>' + val.share + '</td>' + 
        '<td>' + val.effect + '</td>' + 
        '<td>' + val.deemed + '</td>' + 
        '<td>' + val.owned + '</td>' + 
        '<td>' + val.issued + '</td>';
        '</tr>';
    );
 });
```

Haven't tested it just because I don't have a data string, but hopefully that gets you close.

Comment: I'm skeptical that's going to do anything. What would `jQuery.each()` return?

Comment: I see it now - meant to add an appendTo like you have in your example.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much effort you've put into solving this on your own, but in the interest of fairness, I'll explain the thought process a bit. What you need to consider is conceptualizing and separating the "rows" from the "general entity", eg, "I have a table with rows which contain data".

The loop itself runs when creating the rows, and has to be performed as a separate action from creating the `table` itself. Even if you embed the loop logic into the `table` construction itself (as far as the markup generation itself goes, which I consider bad practice), you still have to consider each row as the result of a loop run, distinct from the `table`, `thead`, and `tbody`. Note, even with the rows (`tr`), you have another (*potential*) loop requirement in each cell in the row (`td`). In this case you don't need a loop at that level, but that points to conceptualizing the rudiments of loop design and utilization.

Here is a method using jQuery element caching and a [`jQuery.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) loop, which is a type of `foreach` loop. Note, in Javascript there is no dedicated `foreach` loop; there is, however, `for(var i in object)`, which allows you to iterate over an object of this kind.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $table = $('<table>'),
        $tbody = $('<tbody>'),
        $thead = $('<thead>' +
                   '<tr>' +
                   '<th>OwnedBy</th>' +
                   '<th>ShareClass</th>' +
                   '<th>EffectiveInterest</th>' +
                   '<th>DeemedInterest</th>' +
                   '<th>SharesOwned</th>' +
                   '<th>SharesIssued</th>' +
                   '</tr>' +
                   '</thead>'),
        $tr = $('<tr>'),
        data = {
            grp1: {
                Id: 'id1',
                share: 'share',
                deemed: 'deemed',
                effect: 'effect',
                owned: 'owned',
                issued: 'issued'
            },
            grp2: {
                Id: 'id2',
                share: 'share',
                deemed: 'deemed',
                effect: 'effect',
                owned: 'owned',
                issued: 'issued'
            },
            grp3: {
                Id: 'id3',
                share: 'share',
                deemed: 'deemed',
                effect: 'effect',
                owned: 'owned',
                issued: 'issued'
            }
        };

    $table
        .append($thead, $tbody)
        .appendTo(document.body);

    jQuery.each(data, function(i, val) {
        $tr.clone()
            .appendTo($tbody)
            .append(
                '<td>' + val.Id +'</td>' +
                '<td>' + val.share + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + val.effect + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + val.deemed + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + val.owned + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + val.issued + '</td>'
            );
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YFwTe/

Comment: Hi thanks for your valuable code and comments.I will follow that.I tried your code but i cant get the solution.I had only grp:1 there i get the database values like data.id,data,share etc...when i run this again am gettng only the first row,but am having five rows for that to display!

Comment: If you're trying to add a single row to a preexisting element, then you'll need a reference to the element (`var $table = $('#myTable')`) and then you'll need to `$table.append()` each row. So you'll need to reorganize your `success` handler so it doesn't create the table, but appends rows to a table that already exists.